# columnvalue changed event in kendoGrid

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I am getting my head around the KendoGrid. This sample I downloaded has a 'Title' column and 'City' column. The title column is editable but I would like to add a business rule that when the title is the same as the 'City'value it should become noneditable. Also I would like the change the style of the title background to grey or something to make it look like you cant edit this anymore. The grid looks like this:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data    : createRandomData(50),
        pageSize: 10,
        schema  : {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    id       : { type: 'number' },
                    FirstName: { type: 'string' },
                    LastName : { type: 'string' },
                    City     : { type: 'string' },
                    Title    : { type: 'string' },
                    BirthDate: { type: 'date' },
                    Age      : { type: 'number' }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    editable  : "incell",
    pageable  : {
        refresh  : true,
        pageSizes: true
    },
    columns   : [
        {
            field: "FirstName",
            width: 90,
            title: "First Name"
        } ,
        {
            field: "LastName",
            width: 90,
            title: "Last Name"
        } ,
        {
            width: 100,
            field: "City"
        } ,
        {
            field: "Title"
        } ,
        {
            field   : "BirthDate",
            title   : "Birth Date",
            template: '#= kendo.toString(BirthDate,"dd MMMM yyyy") #'
        } ,
        {
            width: 50,
            field: "Age"
        }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

fid:http://jsfiddle.net/d5j6K/

Comment: I couldn't get it to disable the field but I got an event on edit.  Then I tried to tie that to a blur event for when they tabbed out.  No matter what I tried, I couldn't get the input to be disabled.  Here's an updated fiddle.  Open dev tools and the debugger will catch http://jsfiddle.net/VtoCorleone/d5j6K/1/

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to do it through custom editor or through the edit event of the Grid. Pretty similar case is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067382/change-cell-styling-in-kendogrid/22081206#22081206).