# change cell styling in KendoGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Just discovered the KendoGrid and was trying to change the style of an individual column(cell) after changing another cellvalue. For example I have a grid with a shipname and shipcity column. Suppose I have a business rule that says :

```
'Make shipcity cell value disabled when the shipname on the same row has the same value'
```

I found this sample which uses the blur event which I probably use, what would be a good way of implementing this rule?

Also nice to know your opinion in relation to asp.net mvc integration.

jsfiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/dingen2010/begjT/1/

Answer (score 0):

Updated the link:

`You can try the updated fiddle example` **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/begjT/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Basically conditional editor templates are not supported out of the box. You have two options.

Either use the **[edit](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-edit)** event of the Grid find the editor inside **e.containder** and disable it the way it needs to be (if using Kendo widget use the enable(false) method, or add the readonly attribute if regular input).

The other options is to define custom editor like demonstrated in [this JsBin example](http://jsbin.com/IhiB/1/edit).